# Persistence functionality for ActiveModel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, activemodel

I have a class `Document` that inherits from another class `MyGem::Record`. I am "mixing in" `ActiveModel` functionality so that instances look like `ActiveRecord` objects. I am not inheriting from `ActiveRecord::Base` because I am already inheriting from another class.

I was wondering if I could somehow include some database persistence functionality for my `ActiveModel` flavored class. I could define my own `save` and `update` methods, but I would prefer not to.

Alternatively, would it be possible do something like `include ActiveRecord` to get this functionality in my class?

I know that DataMapper could handle this for me, but I would like to use the `ActiveRecord` model here if possible.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for the `ActiveRecord::Persistence` module: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html.

Include that in your model and it'll give you the methods you are looking for.